# How to get the drag destination url when I drag item form NSCollectionView to Finder

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I am developing a function that copy the file to Finder when I drag a NSCollectionViewItem to Finder,so I implement the following delegate:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)cv writeItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard
{

    NSMutableArray *urls = [NSMutableArray array];
    [indexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         NSDictionary *dictionary = [[cv content] objectAtIndex:idx];
         [urls addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:KEY_URL]];
     }];

    if ([urls count] > 0)
    {
        [pasteboard clearContents];
        BOOL result = [pasteboard writeObjects:urls];
        return result;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

or this way:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)cv writeItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard
{

    NSMutableArray *urls = [NSMutableArray array];
    [indexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         NSDictionary *dictionary = [[cv content] objectAtIndex:idx];
         [urls addObject:[[dictionary objectForKey:KEY_URL] path]];
     }];

    [pasteboard declareTypes:@[NSFilenamesPboardType] owner:self];
    [pasteboard setPropertyList:urls forType:NSFilenamesPboardType];

    return YES;
}
```

both of them work fine.

Now I really want to get the drag destination url for other function.
Anybody can help me to work it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

-(BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)cv writeItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard
{

```
NSMutableArray *urls = [NSMutableArray array];
[indexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
 {
     NSDictionary *dictionary = [[cv content] objectAtIndex:idx];
     [urls addObject:[[dictionary objectForKey:KEY_URL] path]];
 }];

[pasteboard clearContents];

return [pasteboard writeObjects:urls];
```

}